# How to show a matrix can't be written as exponential?

Tags: lie-groups, matrices, lie-algebras

How can I show the matrix 
$$A = \left(
\begin{array}{c c}
-2 & 0  \\
0 & -1  \\
\end{array} 
\right)$$

can't be written as $A = exp(a)$?

I've tried to write A like

$$A =  \left(
\begin{array}{c c}
2 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
\end{array} 
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c c}
-1 & 0  \\
0 & -1  \\
\end{array} 
\right) = BC$$
B and C can be reached by the exponential map:
$$ BC = exp(b)exp(c)$$
$$ b = \left(
\begin{array}{c c}
0 & \pi  \\
-\pi & 0  \\
\end{array} 
\right) $$
$$ c = \left(
\begin{array}{c c}
\log(2) & 0  \\
0 & 0  \\
\end{array} 
\right) $$

Using the Backer-Campbell-Hausdorff formula the trace of $a'=b+c+\frac{1}{2}[b,c]+...$ seems to be different from log(2) (which must be the trace of the ipotetically matrix $a$) but I've computed only the first three orders using:
$$ [b,c] = \log(2) b$$

Comment: It most certainly can be written as an exponential of an imaginary matrix $a$: set the diagonals of $a$ to equal $\log(-2),\log(-1)$ with appropriate choice of branch. Do you mean there is no real matrix?

Answer (score 5):

Note that if $A = \exp(B),$ then $B$ must commute with $A$, hence must also be diagonal.
Let $B = [b_{ij}]$. Then $\exp(b_{11}) =-2$ and $\exp(b_{22}) = -1.$ Therefore  $b_{11}$ and $b_{22}$ are not real.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would be interested in [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Calculating_the_logarithm_of_a_diagonalizable_matrix)? By this method, we know that the matrix would have to be complex to cope with the logarithms of negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that every invertible complex matrix is the $exp$ of some complex matrix. This should have told straight away that there exists an $a$ (complex matrix) with the property you seek.