# Prove $2 \times 2$ real matrix is not the exponential of some other real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

How do I prove that the real matrix $A$, where
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 0\\ 
 0&-5 
\end{pmatrix}$$
can not be written es the exponential of another real matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A real $2\times2$ matrix $X$ has either two real eigenvalues or a conjugate pair of non-real eigenvalues.

If $X$ has two real eigenvalues, then $e^X$ has two positive eigenvalues and hence it isn't equal to $A$.

If $X$ has a conjugate pair of non-real eigenvalues, then $e^X$ has a conjugate pair of eigenvalues too and so it still cannot possibly be equal to $A$.

Comment: See as well the solutions of Geoff Robinson to similar questions : (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/934401)(https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200792)